# Modify existing xlsx sheet containing graphs and charts

Tags: python-2.7, perl

I already have xlsx which consists of 9 sheets, out of which 1-7 sheet consists of graph while 8 and 9 sheets are blank. What I need to do is write some data in 8th and 9th sheet. Well I tried this using python but after wring the data in the xlsx sheet the graph and charts disappears.

Below code I have tried below perl code to modify the existing xls sheet
*Note: Here I have converted the xlsx into xls and reused it.*

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;


my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
my $template = $parser->Parse('TEMP.XLS');

my $worksheet = $template->worksheet('8');
my $row  = 0;
my $col  = 0;

$worksheet->AddCell( $row, $col, 'New string' );
$worksheet->AddCell( $row, $col + 1, 'Newer' );

$template->SaveAs('newfile.xls');
```

But it resulted as removal of graphs and charts.
Can any one help me to do the same in perl or python.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: have you tried Spreadsheet::XLSX?

Answer (score 1):

This code will keep the old and let you add some new code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
use Spreadsheet::Read;
use Data::Dumper;

# read the file
my $book = ReadData ('Factura.xls');
my @data;
my @sheets = (0..1);
my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'Factura_1.xls' );
my $worksheet;
# save the old data 
foreach my $sheet (1 .. ($#sheets+1)) {
   my @rows = Spreadsheet::Read::rows($book->[$sheet]);
   $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet($sheet);
  foreach my $i (1 .. scalar @rows) {
    foreach my $j (1 .. scalar @{$rows[$i-1]}) {
       $worksheet->write($i-1, $j-1, $rows[$i-1][$j-1] );
       my $chart = $workbook->add_chart( type => 'bar',  embedded => 1); 
     $chart->add_series(
      name   => '='."1".'!$A$0',
      values => '='."1".'!$A$2:$A$15',
   );
   $worksheet->insert_chart( 'E2', $chart, 25, 10 );
    }
  }

}

# write new data 
$worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet(3);
$worksheet->write( 0, 0, 'New string' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but still the graphs, fonts  and formats are not visible in the new excel sheet...

Comment: Hi @Hiten Chedda i've inserted some small to create charts.